# How to copy file from google cloud bucket to google cloud vm instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I copy google cloud bucket files to a google cloud vm instance?

I tried this command:

```
gsutil cp gs://xxx.com/photo.tar.gz myvm-vm:/var/www/html/
```

But it gives me this error:

> Copying gs://xxx.com/poto.tar.gz... Skipping attempt to download to
> filename ending with slash (myvm-vm::\var\www\html)). This typically
> happens when using gsutil to download from a subdirectory created by
> the Cloud Console (https://cloud.google.com/console)
>
> Operation completed over 1 objects/11.2 GiB.

Answer (score 4):

The error that is prompting you means that is trying to access to a file ending with slash (myvm-vm::\var\www\html). That's not the correct way to do that, instead, you have to ssh into your Compute Engine instance (with at least "Storage Read only" permissions) and then run the command

```
sudo gsutil cp gs://<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/<YOUR_FILE_NAME> /var/www/html/
```